# Drawing a table with arrows crossing each other in LaTeX

Tags: tables, pdftex, tkz-graph

Can one help me to create the following table in LaTeX. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. In the meantime you can create, with a full compilable code .tex, your table with https://www.tablesgenerator.com/.

Comment: @Sebastiano Tnx for the information. I was wondering that how to include those crossing arrows.

Comment: You create your table after we help you.

Comment: That's great. Waiting patiently....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to begin with (you can try and answer to your other question about arrow and tabulars with the same approach).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{every node/.style={inner xsep=10pt, inner ysep=6pt}}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture] \node (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
    \sf
    
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \tikzmark{a1}{\textbf{AA}} & \tikzmark{b1}{} & \tikzmark{c1}{\textbf{BB}} \\
        \hline
        \tikzmark{a2}{A} & \tikzmark{b2}{} & \tikzmark{c2}{1} \\
        \hline
        \tikzmark{a3}{B} & \tikzmark{b3}{} & \tikzmark{c3}{2} \\
        \hline
        \tikzmark{a4}{C} & \tikzmark{b4}{} & \tikzmark{c4}{3} \\
        \hline
        \tikzmark{a5}{D} & \tikzmark{b5}{} & \tikzmark{c5}{4} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    overlay,
    remember picture,
    arr/.style={-stealth, blue, line width=2pt}]
    
    \foreach \k in {2,...,5}
        \draw[arr] (a\k.east) -- (c\k.west);

    \node[below=20pt] (ending) at (b5.south) {};
    \draw[arr] (b1.south) -- (ending);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular with crossing arrows]

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much indeed!